# create a table in Redshift by adding columns of the other two tables

Tags: sql, join, sum, amazon-redshift, full-outer-join

I want to create a table in Redshift by adding columns of the other two tables.

Table 1
[image: Table 1 data]

Table 2
[image: Table 2 data]

Want to create new table on following conditions

1. if table1.sid = table2.sid 
   then t1.totalcorrect+t2.totalcorrect, t1.totalquestions+t2.totalquestions. that is s4 to s7
2. else data from both tables as it is

Expected output
[image: Output table]

Using joins resulting table gives me only S4 to S7 and not other columns as required. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a `full join`:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.sid, t2.sid) sid, 
    coalesce(t1.totalcorrect,   0) + coalesce(t2.totalcorrect,   0) totalcorrect,
    coalesce(t1.totalquestions, 0) + coalesce(t2.totalquestions, 0) totalquestions
from t1 
full join t2 on t2.sid = t1.sid
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, and I'm not sure which would be faster in Redshift.  One is `union all` and `group by`:

```
select sid, sum(totalcorrect) as totalcorrect, sum(totalquestions) as totalquestions
from ((select sid, totalcorrect, totalquestions
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select sid, totalcorrect, totalquestions
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by sid;
```

The second uses `full join`, for which I recommend using the `using` clause:

```
select sid,
       coalesce(t1.totalcorrect, 0) + coalesce(t2.totalcorrect, 0) as totalcorrect,
       coalesce(t1.totalquestions, 0) + coalesce(t2.totalquestions, 0) as totalquestions
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (sid);
```

There are differences between these two approaches.  The first guarantees one row per `sid` in the result set, even if there are duplicates in one of the tables.  The first also combines `NULL` values of `sid` into a single row.